# Using the link to Set up a Personal Campaign Page gives 404 page error

Tags: personal-campaign-pages

Sorry, I'm a newbee at CiviCRM, and frankly, I find the instructions aren't so clear. I'm trying to set up Personal Campaign pages for a fundraiser we are doing. I enabled the Personal Campaign Page settings on my contribution page, but when I click on the link it provides, it goes to a 404 page error. So I figured that maybe I needed to add short code to a new Wordpress page. The CiviCRM component isn't giving me the option for Personal Campaign page. What is the short code I should be using?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out. I had deleted the CiviCRM page so that's why it wasn't working.

Thank you!